# AddClass with jQuery target help needed

Tags: jquery

I have a the following HTML

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>
     <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck">Click
  </legend>
  content
<fieldset>
```

I'm trying to add class when the checkbox is selected and remove when unchecked. Should't something like this work:

```
$(".myCheck").change(function() {           
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent("fieldset").addClass("myClass");
    } else {
        $(this).parent("fieldset").removeClass("myClass");
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.parent()` only traverses one level up.
But as per the HTML you have fieldset is two levels up.
Use parents or closest.

i.e:

```
$(".myCheck").change(function() {                
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){         
        $(this).closest("fieldset").addClass("myClass");     
        } else {         
        $(this).closest("fieldset").removeClass("myClass");     
    } 
});
```

or

```
$(".myCheck").change(function() {                
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){         
        $(this).parents("fieldset").addClass("myClass");     
        } else {         
        $(this).parents("fieldset").removeClass("myClass");     
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.parent()` will give you the direct parent in this case it is `<legend/>` you could either do `.parent().parent("fieldset")` or use `.parents("fieldset")` however that will give you ANY parent of `$(this)` that matches `<fieldset/>`

Putting that together you will have something like this:

```
  $(this).parent().parent("fieldset").addClass("myClass");
```

or

```
  $(this).parents("fieldset").first().addClass("myClass");
```

Also you can use `.toggleClass( className, switch )`

```
$(".myCheck").change(function() {           
  $(this).parents("fieldset").first().toggleClass("myClass", $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

**[Code example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/J8Nrg/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$('.myCheck').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('fieldset').toggleClass('myClass', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```